# NGINX: How to concatenate two servers with same address and name

Tags: nginx

Situation:

1. I have many (not defined number) web applications (app1 with the URI "/app1" and app2 with the URI "/app2") that listen the port 80 on the same machine and with the same server_name in configuration files.
2. There is the automation tool that manages the configuration files for each project absolutely separately. Thus I need two different configuration files.
3. If I try to include `server` directives with the same `listen` and `server_name` directives expecting the concatenation of the servers (all directives from the servers works like they are located in one server, I will get the warning `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "some_server_name" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored` and one of the servers will be ignored.
4. One can say "just put `location /app1 {...}` into app1.conf , `location /app2 {...}` into app2.conf, ... , then include this confs into one `server` directive". But it is not an option because I need own `map` directives for each app and `map` directives cannot be incorporated into `server` directive.
5. I cannot use different server_name because it is already with a third-level domain and a fourth-level domain is not really an option.

Question: how to achieve the described "concatenation"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two ideas

### First idea: Separate configuration parts (Not usual view, no isolation)

Inner-`server` and an outer-`server` directives can be put into two other files.

No isolation problem appears here as a problem of overwriting things from app1 by app2 and alerting with errors for not overwritable things.

Note: The example below is only for simple demonstaration and not actual practice.

#### The tree of the file system

```
| /etc/nginx
|-- nginx.conf
|-- conf.d
|--|-- some_server_name_and_port_80.conf
|--|-- some_server_name_and_port_80.outer_server.d
|--|--|-- app1.outer_server.conf
|--|--|-- app2.outer_server.conf
|--|-- some_server_name_and_port_80.inner_server.d
|--|--|-- app1.inner_server.conf
|--|--|-- app2.inner_server.conf
```

#### The file contents

`nginx.conf`:

```
...
http {
    ...
    # If default_type is already defined, just replace its value
    default_type text/plain ;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf ;
}
```

`some_server_name_and_port_80.conf`:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/some_server_name_and_port_80.outer_server.d/*.conf ;
server {
    listen      80 ;
    server_name some_server_name ;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/some_server_name_and_port_80.inner_server.d/*.conf ;
}
```

`app1.outer_server.conf` (for app2 replace `app1` with `app2`):

```
map $request_uri $app1_var {
    ~^/app1(.*) /app$1 ;
    default    $request_uri ;
}
```

`app1.inner_server.conf` (for app2 replace `app1` with `app2`):

```
location /app1/ {
    return 200 "app1: Hello, World! The universal uri is $app1_var" ;
}
```

### Second way: Using different servers and simple routing using proxy_pass (Need attention to the proxy_pass features)

Note: The example below is only for simple demonstaration and not actual practice.

#### The tree of the file system

```
| /etc/nginx
|-- nginx.conf
|-- conf.d
|--|-- some_server_name_and_port_80.conf
|--|-- some_server_name_and_port_80.d
|--|--|-- app1.router.conf
|--|--|-- app2.router.conf
|--|-- app1.conf
|--|-- app2.conf
```

#### The file contents

`nginx.conf`:

```
...
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf ;
}
```

`some_server_name_and_port_80.conf`:

```
server {
    listen      80 ;
    server_name some_server_name ;
    
    # If default_type is already defined, just replace its value
    default_type text/plain ;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/some_server_name_and_port_80.d/*.conf ;
}
```

`app1.router.conf` (for app2 replace `app1` with `app2`, 81 with 82):

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81 ;
}
```

`app1.conf` (for app2 replace `app1` with `app2`, 81 with 82):

```
map $request_uri $app1_var {
    ~^/app1(.*) /app$1 ;
    default    $request_uri ;
}

server {
    listen      81 ;
    server_name some_server_name ;

    location /app1/ {
        return 200 "app1: Hello, World! The universal uri is $app1_var" ;
    }
}
```